# Python dll function return wrong value

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

Using C# I call the dll function as follows:

```
[DllImport("Tnzv01.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
internal static extern unsafe int TnzDDBOpenDatabase(byte[] dbFile, out IntPtr dbhDatabase);

var dbFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FilePath);
var errorCode = TnzDDBOpenDatabase(dbFile, out var dbHandle);
```

It returns `errorCode = 0` and `dbHandle = 0x140e0690`

I'm trying to do this with python:

```
dll = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join("dependence", "Tnzv01.dll"))
tzh_file = bytes(r"D:\PycharmProjects\tnz_analysis_32\new_3000_57_63_421_461_464_2485.tzh", 'ASCII')
open_db_fun = dll.TnzDDBOpenDatabase
open_db_fun.restype = ctypes.c_int
open_db_fun.argtypes = [ctypes.c_byte * 70, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)]
handle = ctypes.c_int(0)
c_tzh_file = (ctypes.c_byte * len(tzh_file))(*tzh_file)
result = open_db_fun(c_tzh_file, handle)
```

But it returns`result = -2147352576` and `handle = c_long(-1)`

Why is python giving the wrong result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more useful to see the actual C prototype, but try the following:

```
dll = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join("dependence", "Tnzv01.dll"))
tzh_file = rb"D:\PycharmProjects\tnz_analysis_32\new_3000_57_63_421_461_464_2485.tzh"
open_db_fun = dll.TnzDDBOpenDatabase
open_db_fun.restype = ctypes.c_int
open_db_fun.argtypes = ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)
handle = ctypes.c_void_p()
result = open_db_fun(tzh_file,ctypes.byref(handle))
```

You may pass the byte string directly assuming the C type for the first parameter is `const char*` and the second parameter is something like `HANDLE*`.  Handles are generally  `void*` under the covers and pointers are 64-bit and `ctypes.c_int` is only 32-bit.  Pass the second parameter by reference since it is an out parameter.